# How to encode parameters for AWS API Gateway (HTTP API)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, urlencode, api-gateway

I am building an HTTP API in AWS Gateway, and I can't understand how to encode the path parameters.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html) says

> API Gateway decodes URL-encoded request parameters before passing them to your backend integration.

But apparently there is more to it than that....

---

I have a route `GET /{example}/thing`, and I want to pass `a/b` as the parameter.

If I request `/a/b/thing`, I get 404 Not Found.

If I request `/a%2Fb/thing`, I get 404 Not Found.

If I request `/a%25Fb/thing`, I get 404 Not Found.

If I request `/a%2525Fb/thing`, I get 200 OK, but the Lambda function gets the parameter `a%2Fb`.

**What encoding does API Gateway (HTTP API) use for its parameters?**

How should encode the parameter `a/b`?